# Measure time per game session

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-analytics

Is it possible to measure the time a user has spend in my game (not overall, only per one session), using only Parse's methods, without any additional code from me?

Or if not possible, using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the user timings, from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/usertimings. This would mean saving the current timestamp in `onCreate`, and logging it in `onDestroy`, or a related place.